# Is it possible to return ng-model from a filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Inside SampleFilter:

```
return $sce.trustAsHtml('<input type="checkbox" ng-model="gender">');
```

View:

```
<span ng-bind-html="gender | SampleFilter"></span> {{gender}}
```

Is this possible? I can see the checkbox being returned but the model `gender` is not binding to `{{gender}}`. Please help

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Filters and ng-bind are not supposed to bind models to inputs.

Comment: Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Explain "this" in _"...doing this"_.

Comment: @Stewie basically, re-binding a model via the filter return value. I need to be able to show a HTML control (textbox, textarea , checkbox etc) based on a model's value and then rebind the same model to that HTML control.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a directive instead of a filter to achieve the same results. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can bind `ng-model` in a filter output. But your output HTML will have the same functionality as normal HTML. So you can use jQuery's event handler to listen to changes of the input field.

```
// bind event listener on input's parent element
// so the event listener will keep the same when parent's child changes
// you have to select 'input' when attaching event handler
$('span).on('change', 'input', function(e) {
  // do something...
});
```